# Trying to Get Current Location integrated with iOS project

Tags: ios, ios6, mapkit

So I'm attempting to integrate the user's current location with my iOS project - I'm using some third part code to build out the map with the pinpoints - I have these frameworks integrated:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
```

here's my code with the pinpoints - any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
#import "asyMap.h"

@implementation asyMap
@synthesize currentAnnotation,mapAnnotations,map,prompt,mapFromLink,selectedAnnotationId,selectedAnnotationIndex,showOthers,useCustomTitle,customTitle;
/**
 * Class constructor
 */
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        useCustomTitle = FALSE;
        mapFromLink = FALSE;
        showOthers = FALSE;
        map = [[asyMapObject alloc] init];
        [map addOnView:self.view];
    }    
    return self;
}

/**
 * Overwrite the set page method in
 * order to show a selected annotation
 * from a link
 */
-(void)setPage:(NSDictionary *)page{
    NSDictionary *metas = [page valueForKey:@"metas"];
    if([metas valueForKey:@"selectedAnnotationPageTitle"] && ![[[metas valueForKey:@"selectedAnnotationPageTitle"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@""] && customTitle == nil){
        useCustomTitle = TRUE;
        NSString *newTitle = [metas valueForKey:@"selectedAnnotationPageTitle"];
        customTitle = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[newTitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    }
    if(useCustomTitle && customTitle != nil){
        NSMutableDictionary *pageWithCustomTitle = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:page];
        [pageWithCustomTitle setValue:customTitle forKey:@"title"];
        [super
         setPage:pageWithCustomTitle];
    }else{
        [super setPage:page];
    }
    if([metas valueForKey:@"annotationFromLink"] && [[[metas valueForKey:@"annotationFromLink"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"yes"] && selectedAnnotationId == nil){
        selectedAnnotationId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[metas valueForKey:@"selectedAnnotation"]];
        mapFromLink = TRUE;
        showOthers = [[[metas valueForKey:@"showOthers"] stringValue] isEqualToString:@"yes"];
    }else if(mapFromLink && selectedAnnotationId != nil){
        mapFromLink = FALSE;
        NSArray *annotations = [page valueForKey:@"annotations"];
        for(int a = 0; a < [annotations count]; a++){
            NSDictionary *annotation = [annotations objectAtIndex:a];
            if([[[annotation valueForKey:@"annotationId"] stringValue] isEqualToString:selectedAnnotationId]){
                mapFromLink = TRUE;
                selectedAnnotationIndex = a;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
/**
 * Set the module's name
 */
-(void)makeProcess{
    [self setModuleName:@"map"];
}
/**
 * Create the basic prompt alert
 */
-(void)buildModule{
    prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[theme asy__:@"Open on the Maps app?"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:[theme asy__:@"No"] otherButtonTitles:[theme asy__:@"Yes"], nil];
}
/**
 * Set the annotations after get the page data
 */
-(void)requestedPage:(NSDictionary *)pageInformation{
    [self setPage:pageInformation];
    if(mapFromLink && !showOthers && [[self getPageMapAnnotations] count] > 0){
        NSArray *pageAnnotations = [self getPageMapAnnotations];
        mapAnnotations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[pageAnnotations objectAtIndex:selectedAnnotationIndex],nil];
    }else{
        mapAnnotations = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self getPageMapAnnotations]];
    }
    [map setMapAnnotations:mapAnnotations andDelegate:self];
    if(mapFromLink){
        [map focusMapOnAnnotationAtIndex:(showOthers ? selectedAnnotationIndex : 0)];
    }
    [map build];
    [self hideLoading];
    [self checkPageOptionButton];
}
/**
 * The module orientation did change
 */
-(void)moduleOrientationDidChange{
    [map setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}

#pragma mark - Map Delegate
/**
 * Check if the annotation has properties for action or the prompt to be opened
 * on the Maps app should appear
 */
-(void)asyMapObject:(asyMapObject *)mapObject didSelectAnnotation:(NSDictionary *)annotation atIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    currentAnnotation = index;
    if([[annotation valueForKey:@"menuId"] isEqualToString:@"0"] &&
       [[annotation valueForKey:@"pageId"] isEqualToString:@"0"] &&
       [[annotation valueForKey:@"link"] isEqualToString:@""] &&
       [[annotation valueForKey:@"url"] isEqualToString:@""] &&
       [[annotation valueForKey:@"phpfile"] isEqualToString:@""]){
        [prompt setTitle:[annotation valueForKey:@"title"]];
        [prompt show];
    }else{
        AppsifymeCore *core = [AppsifymeCore sharedAppsifymeCore];
        [core basicHandlerForMultiActionsOption:annotation];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Alert view delegate
/**
 * Detect if the user wants to open the annotation on the maps app, and if its
 * true, this method build the link and open the app
 */
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex != 1) return;
    AppsifymeCore *core = [AppsifymeCore sharedAppsifymeCore];
    NSDictionary *annotation = [mapAnnotations objectAtIndex:currentAnnotation];
    float latitude = [[annotation valueForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];
    float longitude = [[annotation valueForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];
    if(![core asyiOS6]){
        NSString *pinName = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[core encodeURLParameter:[annotation valueForKey:@"title"]]];
        int zoom = 13;
        NSString *stringURL = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q=%@@%1.6f,%1.6f&z=%d", pinName, latitude, longitude, zoom];
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:stringURL];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }else{
        Class itemClass = [MKMapItem class];
        if (itemClass && [itemClass respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) {
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
            MKPlacemark *placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate addressDictionary:nil];
            MKMapItem *item =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];
            item.name = [[annotation valueForKey:@"title"] stringValue];
            [item openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:nil];
        }
    }
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `init` method, add this line

```
 self.showsUserLocation = YES;
```